# How to create an analog voltmeter in android

Tags: android

Can any one tell how to create android voltmeter GUI and its working please.I used some of the code from android speedometer GUI application but it does not worked properly.can anyone suggest code for android Voltmeter GUI and its operation please. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have hardware/equipment for measurement of volts

Comment: so you can connect the hardware to android device, example: http://www.instructables.com/id/App-inventor-arduino-analog-voltmeter/

Comment: thank u @ozi  this is what exactly looking for this will helps me a little bit it does not contain java code. In the link only arduino code was present in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the hardware to android device, 
An example: http://instructables.com/id/App-inventor-arduino-analog-voltmeter

And for Java Arduino connection, you can find with search on google and you can find an example over here: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/control-an-arduino-from-java/240163864

Comment: Dude @ozi i already did the communication between micro controller and android device but i need to calculate the voltage from android    device ..can you suggest for volt meter GUI android java code

Comment: For interface you can create semi circle progressbar and can give new shape to it. You can start from semi circle progress bar from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499964/android-semi-circle-progress-bar

Comment: But how to add the voltmeter scale to this semi circle dude @ozi

Comment: Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), 
    (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * Math.abs(Math.sin(angle))), false);

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. And in my question scale means not to resize.It means add the text scale that is readings to the arc @ozi...