# Circular progress bar with touch motion

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

Hi i have implemented a countdown timer with a circular progress bar and it is working fine, my problem is i need to add small circle touch motion like Seek bar.
Ex: if i touch the small circle and increase the timer the time should increase if decrease it should decrease. Many are suggested to implement circular seek bar but how to add countdown timer value to seek bar.

Comment: You can give max value to circular seekbar right? And there's one method `onSeekbarChangedListener()` which can be helpful to retrieve the value of current seek position. You can set that value to the timer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499964/android-semi-circle-progress-bar

Comment: @Apurva can u give me any ex or links

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Thanks for your reply and already i have implemented circular progress bar