# How to design Semi Circular Progress bar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-progressbar

Hi I have **implemented a circular progress bar** and it is working fine, Now the problem is i need to **design a semi circular progress bar**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented by clipping a canvas containing an image at an angle (By drawing an arc).

And clip that image by drawing an arc.

Here is how you can do it.

```
//Convert the progress in range of 0 to 100 to angle in range of 0 180. Easy math.
float angle = (progress * 180) / 100;
mClippingPath.reset();
//Define a rectangle containing the image
RectF oval = new RectF(mPivotX, mPivotY, mPivotX + mBitmap.getWidth(), mPivotY + mBitmap.getHeight());
//Move the current position to center of rect
mClippingPath.moveTo(oval.centerX(), oval.centerY());
//Draw an arc from center to given angle
mClippingPath.addArc(oval, 180, angle);
//Draw a line from end of arc to center
mClippingPath.lineTo(oval.centerX(), oval.centerY());
```

once you get the path, you can use `clipPath function` to clip the canvas in that path.

```
canvas.clipPath(mClippingPath);
```

Take a look at [Semi Circle Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499964/android-semi-circle-progress-bar) for more easy and usefull details.

---

***Note that clipPath function doesn't work if the hardware acceleration is turned on. You can turn off the hardware acceleration only for that view.***

```
//Turn off hardware accleration
  semiCircleProgressBarView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

As and when the progress changes you can set the progressbar by calling function,

```
semiCircleProgressBarView.setClipping(progress);
```