# How can i design semi circle progress bar in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

i need to design below type of design in android. how can i design  semi circular design in circle in android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQy2r.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499964/android-semi-circle-progress-bar

Answer (score 1):

Define `ProgressBar` like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="200"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Create drawable:

`circular` (API Level < 21):

```
<shape
   android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
   android:shape="ring"
   android:thickness="5sp" >
   <solid android:color="@color/someColor" />
</shape>
```

`circular` (API Level >= 21):

```
<shape
   android:useLevel="true"
   android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
   android:shape="ring"
   android:thickness="5sp" >
   <solid android:color="@color/someColor" />
</shape>
```

`useLevel` is `false` by default in API Level 21.

Now since we have set `max = 200`, to achieve semi circle, range of the progress should be `0` to `100`. You can play around with these values to achieve desired shape.

Thus use it like this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (Progressbar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setProgress(value); // 0 <= value <= 100
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.but i think this one is for progress bar shape , but i need do in xml file . did you seen the image which i was uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library it may help you :

https://github.com/glomadrian/velocimeter-view.git